# Asset Library issue in iOS - 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

i am using asset library for getting image from url , my code is

```
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset){     
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    UIImage *largeimage;

    if (iref) {
        largeimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
    }

    [self customeButtonCreated:self];

    NSData* thumbImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    btn1.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    [btn1 setTag:tag];

    //[media_id addObject:[allKey objectAtIndex:0]];     
    [btnURl addObject:imagePath];

    UIImage *tempImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:thumbImageData];
    [btn1 setImage:largeimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn1.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;           
    [tempImage release];

    [newView addSubview:btn1];
    [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [thumbImageData release];

    imgcount++;

    NSLog(@"Iamge count ---%d",imgcount);
    tag++;
};

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror){
    NSLog(@"Cannot get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
};


if ([seprateArr count] == 2) {
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=%@&ext=%@",[seprateArr objectAtIndex:0],[seprateArr objectAtIndex:1]]];
    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:url resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];
}
```

it is working fine in ios - 4 or below but in ios - 5 it is not entering in block and showing errir

> **Cannot get image - Global denied access**

any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me in ios 4.0 as well as ios 5.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
NSString *photoName;
NSString *photoUrl;

 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) 
    {
        if(result != NULL) 
        {
            NSArray *arrKeys = [[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]allKeys];             
            if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType]isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto])
            {
                if([[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]>=5.0))
                {
                    photoName = [[result defaultRepresentation]UTI];

                }
                else
                {
                    photoName = [[result defaultRepresentation]filename];

                }
                //Your code here
                photoUrl = [[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]objectForKey:[arrKeys objectAtIndex:0]];

            }
        }
    };

    void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) 
    {
        if(group != nil) 
        {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        }
    };
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }];

    [pool release];
```

Comment: what is photoName here ? name of image ?

Comment: means i have to use [UIImage imageNamed:photoName];

Comment: photoName is title of image and photoUrl its asset url. You can access like this UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:photoUrl]]];

Comment: where i can use photoName ? and what is the data type of it ? and where can i declare it ?

Comment: it is title of image u can show all titles in tableview and each has asset url. or in scrollview where it shows all images and below each image there is label which shows its title

Comment: what is the data type of it ? and where can i declare it ?

Comment: it is photoName is string and photoUrl is also a string u can have array of images with title and its url.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12482/discussion-between-safecase-and-pjr)